# Await for IEnumerable items, (wait after await)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I have this iterator- return type is `IEnumerable<Task<Event>>` so that I can await for each item later:

```
private IEnumerable<Task<Event>> GetEventsAsync(long length)
{
    var pos = _reader.BaseStream.Position;
    while (_reader.BaseStream.Position - pos < length)
    {
        yield return ReadEvent(); // this method is async
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass this in to constructor.

```
private async Task<EventManager> ReadEventManagerAsync()
{
    // some other stuff
    var length = Reverse(await _reader.ReadInt32()); // bytes to read
    var events = GetEventsAsync(length); // cant await iterator. so use linq
    return new EventManager(events.Select(async e => await e).Select(x => x.Result));
}
```

The constructor takes this parameter.

```
internal EventManager([NotNull, NoEnumeration]IEnumerable<Event> events) {...}
```

Will this code run asynchronously?

Because I cant await inside lambda even if method is marked as async. I tried to do some hack.

I Understand why `Select(async e => await e)` returns `IEnumerable<Task<Event>>` because `async e => await e` is async method, which return type must be wrapped inside `Task`

My question is will `.Select(x => x.Result)` still run async? because I'm awaiting items before this so this shouldn't be a problem right? its like writing this

```
await e;
return e.Result; // is it safe?
```

---

I don't want to use Task.WhenAll because that will enumerate all stuff and that's the thing I'm trying to avoid. I want to keep this iterator untouched until its passed in constructor. I want to keep the execution deferred. (I will use factory method if this approach is not possible)

Comment: If you are not enumerating this query in constructor, then it will not run at all. Please show constructor code

Comment: I understand, I'm enumerating this query inside constructor. I use bunch of self made methods so that doesn't really help. I have something like this `UnknownEvents = events.Sieve(AEvents).Sieve(BEvents).ToReadOnlyCollection(x => x);` this will enumerate all the things. @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: yield does not work with await as expected, may be next c# version will have better provision. As of now, you just have to await and store event in a list, take a look at my answer. Also if your ReadEvent depends on `Stream.Position` you cannot use `Task.WhenAll` or any other way but simply enumerate and store result in list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will this code run asynchronously?

No. When the enumerable is enumerated, it will run synchronously, complete with [possibility of deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

`Select(async e => await e)` doesn't do anything. It's the same as `Select(e => e)`. It is **not** the same as `await e;`.

The whole converting-stream-to-`IEnumerable<T>` is extremely odd. Perhaps you meant to convert it to `IObservable<T>`?

> I will use factory method if this approach is not possible

Yes, you cannot use `await` in a constructor, and blocking can cause deadlocks. An asynchronous factory method is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will run synchronously (constructors can't be async after all).

That doesn't mean your performance is impacted if (since) you never actually execute the tasks. `events.Select(async e => await e).Select(x => x.Result)` returns an enumerable after all. It won't call the first `Select`, which means that the awaited code is never called.

Comment: So if I enumerate this inside constructor it will run synchronously? then I think i have no choice but to store results in list as @akashkava suggested and pass list to constructor.

Comment: Forcing it in a list will make the code run already, so not sure if that is what you want. @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: Yes. I wanted to make things look cool, (and prevent extra list creation how ever GC will handle it btw) but I think that's all I can do for now, thanks for your answer, I accept both answer if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

`yield` does not work with `await` as expected, may be next c# version will have better provision. As of now, you just have to await and store event in a list. Also if your `ReadEvent` depends on `Stream.Position` you cannot use `Task.WhenAll` or any other way but simply enumerate and store result in list.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> GetEventsAsync(long length)
{
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    var pos = _reader.BaseStream.Position;
    while (_reader.BaseStream.Position - pos < length)
    {
        // if ReadEvent depends on _reader.BaseStream.Postion
        // you cannot use Task.WhenAll, because it executes all
        // tasks in parallel, where else, you must await to finish
        // your previous ReadEvent
        Event e = await ReadEvent(); // this method is async
        events.Add(e);
    }
    return events;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WhenAll` for this, and await for it asynchronously.

```
private async Task<EventManager> ReadEventManagerAsync()
{
    // some other stuff
    var length = Reverse(await _reader.ReadInt32()); // bytes to read
    var events = GetEventsAsync(length); // cant await iterator. so use linq
    await Task.WhenAll(events);
    return new EventManager(events.Select(x => x.Result));
}
```

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` will execute each operation in parallel, making `Stream.Position` return invalid position.